# $_GET in frinedly url (.htaccess) isn't working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have a .htaccess and it work fine in some of conditions when i use $_GET but in order don't send $_GET

```
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^playlist/(.+) radios-show.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^player-free/(.+) player-free.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^locutores/(.+) locutores-show.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pedidos-musicais/(.+) pedidos-musicais.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^incorporar/(.+) incorporar.php?link=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^buscar/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) search.php?tabela=$1&busca=$2&pagina=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^buscar/(.+)/(.+) search.php?tabela=$1&busca=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^usuarios/(.+) usuarios-show.php?link=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^minhas-radios/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) minhas-radios.php?orderItem=$1&order=$2&pagina=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^minha-radio/(.+) minha-radio.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^opcoes-radio/(.+) opcoes-radio.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editar-radio/(.+) editar-radio.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^locutar/(.+) locutar.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^estatisticas/(.+) estatisticas.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrar-locutores/(.+) administrar-locutores.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrar-pedidos/(.+) administrar-pedidos.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^minhas-favoritas/(.+) minhas-favoritas.php?pagina=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^meus-amigos/(.+) meus-amigos.php?pagina=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

these lines work fine thay pass the $_GET['link'] to the code

```
RewriteRule ^playlist/(.+) radios-show.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^buscar/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) search.php?tabela=$1&busca=$2&pagina=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^buscar/(.+)/(.+) search.php?tabela=$1&busca=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^usuarios/(.+) usuarios-show.php?link=$1 [L]
```

but these not send the $_GET['link'] to the code and don't pass nothing I already tried to use $_REQUEST but it don't work too.

```
RewriteRule ^player-free/(.+) player-free.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^locutores/(.+) locutores-show.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pedidos-musicais/(.+) pedidos-musicais.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^incorporar/(.+) incorporar.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^minhas-radios/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) minhas-radios.php?orderItem=$1&order=$2&pagina=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^minha-radio/(.+) minha-radio.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^opcoes-radio/(.+) opcoes-radio.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editar-radio/(.+) editar-radio.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^locutar/(.+) locutar.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^estatisticas/(.+) estatisticas.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrar-locutores/(.+) administrar-locutores.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrar-pedidos/(.+) administrar-pedidos.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^minhas-favoritas/(.+) minhas-favoritas.php?pagina=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^meus-amigos/(.+) meus-amigos.php?pagina=$1 [L]
```

In code every one work, they found the page, but only don't send the $_GET, I have to servers to test in one everything works fine, but in another don't work. I think it can be some configuration different to one server from another, but the server that work, I don't have full access to see what is hapenning.

I already tried and it don't worked

> RewriteRule ^meus-amigos/(.+) meus-amigos.php?pagina=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have `MultiViews` options turned on in your Apache. Turn it off by placing this line at the top:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.